# windows forms can't add more components

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I want to build a form that has 100 label and 100 text box

what I did is:

1. add new form
2. add panel to that form using drag and drop
3. change the `dock` property of that panel to **fill**
4. change the `AutoScroll` property to **True**
5. start adding the labels and text boxes using drag and drop

#### The problem

I added like 40 labels and text boxes but I can't add any more because I can't expand the form nor the label vertically.

#### Note

I can minimize the size of the panel and a vertical scroll bar appears. (maybe this information helps you to help me).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the controls from code, rather than from the designer?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I hope I could add them from designer, if there is no solution to my problem then okay I will go to code.

Comment: Consider using a grid component. I know this does not solve your problem but your code will most likely be smaller and much easier to maintain.

Comment: @clausc there is no `Grid` compoent in my vs 2012

Comment: 100 labels and 100 textboxes would make ugly user interface and that would make your code ugly too. Consider using some other compoenent like grid or list view or something..

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli `DataGridView` is what clausc talks about

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Can you explain your use case? You might get a better alternative.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma a customer asked for a small windows application to enter the data. he gave me the data in an excel sheel with 100 column :)

Comment: Do you have a DataGridView control in the "Data" group of your toolbox?

Comment: @Hambone yes I do. I found it

Comment: should I add this data grid in the designer and then start adding the 100 label and text boex to it from code?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Use DataGridView, alternatively you may use any commercial grid like FlexGrid by ComponentOne.

Comment: It is a grid, you dont need to add textbox/ label, @MarcoDinatsoli, REFER [THIS](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial)

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma sorry didn't get you, you mean that if i use grid i won't need to add labels and text boxes?

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma I don't have database to bind the data from

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, YES. The grid is a big table where each cell has its own editor(TextBox by default). So when you've added a grid and specified no. of rows and columns, you can easily reference each cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57752/discussion-between-nilay-vishwakarma-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set parent form's properties `AutoSize` and `AutoScroll` to **true**. Then disable docking for your panel. This way you can set any size to panel and scroll form contents to add new controls. When panel design is done, set docking to **Fill** again.

Or you can set position for newly added controls using Properties panel. This will move controls to appropriate position on the panel.

Comment: you are my god, TTTTTTThank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A data entry window with that many text boxes is going to require scrolling.  So set the Panel's AutoScrollMinSize property to, say, (1000, 1000) as a first guess.  You'll see the scrollbars appear.  They work at design time as well, allowing you to scroll the panel and place the controls.  High odds you should be using a DataGridView btw.

Something that needs to be said: the odds that you can get a human to enter 100 data items without any mistake are very close to zero.  A very frustrating job for the hapless user, it will take him 10 or more minutes only to arrive at failure.  Create a *user friendly* UI, one that partitions the data entry job in small steps that can be successfully completed.  Automatically solves this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample method I've used to add an unknown number of controls to a form. The trick is a FlowLayoutPanel.

As has been said before: you don't want 100 manually added controls on your page.

```
private void AddMappingControls() {

            HeaderFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();
            MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();

            Label sourceHeaderLabel = new Label();
            sourceHeaderLabel.Text = "Velden in Excel (bron)";
            sourceHeaderLabel.Name = "BronLabel";
            sourceHeaderLabel.Width = MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Width / 2 - 20;
            HeaderFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(sourceHeaderLabel);

            Label destinationHeaderLabel = new Label();
            destinationHeaderLabel.Text = "Velden in Word sjabloon (bestemming)";
            destinationHeaderLabel.Name = "BestemmingLabel";
            destinationHeaderLabel.Width = MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Width / 2 - 20;
            HeaderFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(destinationHeaderLabel);

            foreach (string destination in this.destinationFields) {

                ComboBox sourceFieldComboBox = new ComboBox();
                sourceFieldComboBox.BindingContext = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext();
                sourceFieldComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                //sourceFieldComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                sourceFieldComboBox.Name = destination + "ComboBox";
                sourceFieldComboBox.ValueMember = destination;
                sourceFieldComboBox.DataSource = this.sourceFields;
                sourceFieldComboBox.Width = MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Width / 2 - 20;
                MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(sourceFieldComboBox);

                Label nameLabel = new Label();
                nameLabel.Text = destination;
                nameLabel.Name = destination + "Label";
                nameLabel.Width = MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Width / 2 - 20;
                MappingFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(nameLabel);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I meant exactly the same as MeanGreen but he was first. I have created sample solution: https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share?s=i9N7raPPQPEjOdHPRn99uE